# How can I update value of likes variable in firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
DocumentReference tweetDocProfile = tweetsRef.doc(tweet.authorId).collection('userTweets').doc(tweet.id);
tweetDocProfile.get().then((doc) {
    int likes = doc.get('likes');
    tweetDocProfile.update({'likes' : likes+1});
});
```

Value of `likes` is not updating in Firebase, I am able to update it in code but update is not working I guess

Comment: Your code isn't checking for errors at all.  Both the `get()` and the `update()` might fail, but without checking for errors, you'll never know what went wrong.

Comment: Aside from Doug's feedback, consider [using the atomic increment operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value) for this use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
DocumentReference tweetDocProfile = tweetsRef.doc(tweet.authorId).collection('userTweets').doc(tweet.id);
tweetDocProfile.get().then((doc) { 
  int likes = doc.get('likes'); 
  tweetDocProfile.update({'likes' : int.parse(likes)+1}); 
});
```

Comment: No, this will be helpful if the variable is not an integer, but likes variable is an integer so, no luck with it

Comment: I this is working.

int likes = doc['likes']; //Access 'likes' directly from the document snapshot

Comment: yes, but this does not help me with updating the value in the firebase

Answer (score 0):

try this way, it is safer to modify,
It saves you a get request and the script internally uses a transaction so it doesn't overwrite the data.

```
DocumentReference userTweetRef = tweetsRef.doc(tweet.authorId).collection('userTweets').doc(tweet.id);
userTweetRef.update({ likes: FieldValue.increment(1) });
```